# How to determine what page called called the php include?

Tags: php, html, navbar

I am working on an established website which has many problems in it. I am trying to incorporate a new navbar that will be coded in a 'header.php' file. I want to call it in the index.php and other pages using `<?php include('header.php') ?>` but there are differences in the pages and it needs the header.php to be dynamic. I want the header.php to have some slight changes when called by a specific page. How can I dynamically change the header.php file depending on what page called it?

This is my code:

HEADER.PHP

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angel-header.css">
<!-- RENAME THIS CSS FILE APPROPRIATELY -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="m-price_update price_starway vb lang-en webp">

  <header class="angelmod-site-header">
    <div class="angelmod-wrapper">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/logo_sb.png" alt="Small Builders">
      </a>
      <nav class="angelmod-site-nav">
        <ul class="angelmod-nav-list">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Signup</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="angel-mod-navbtn">
        <div class="angel-mod-navbtn-bars"></div>
        <div class="angel-mod-navbtn-bars"></div>
        <div class="angel-mod-navbtn-bars"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/angel-header.js"></script>
    <!-- RENAME THIS JS FILE APPROPRIATELY -->
  </header>
```

I have a products.php file that needs to change the body tag to: `<body class="m-price_update price_starway vb lang-en webp">` right now the header.php only have `<body>`.

Please don't ask why the body differs from page to page, it's the previous dev's work and I am tasked to not change those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any variables defined in the file doing the including will be available in the included file. Just define a variable in the including file that identifies what needs to be done in the included file.

```
// products.php
$include_option = 'products';
include('header.php');
```

Then in the included file, refer to that variable at the appropriate place to conditionally do whatever needs to be done:

```
// header.php
...
<?php if ($include_option == 'products') { ?>
    <body class="m-price_update price_starway vb lang-en webp">
<?php } else { ?>
    <body class="something else">
<?php } ?>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not that proficient in php yet. I didn't know that variables can be reused. I forgot that the page will be rendered in the server. Haha. Thanks for this. This will work.